# Auto-suggest text field on search form for Silverstripe?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, silverstripe

https://www.tripadvisor.com.ph/Hotels

Where it says Enter your city or hotel.  As you start typing, suggestions show up below.

I want to have the same function on my search form.  Any ideas on how to do it?

Here's my code:

```
public function Form()
{
    $QualificationTypes = array("Any degree");
    foreach (QualificationType::get()->filter("ParentID", 0)->sort("Name") as $QualificationType) {
        $QualificationTypes[$QualificationType->Name] = $QualificationType->Children()->sort("Name")->map()->toArray();
    }


    $fields      = new FieldList(array(
        GroupedDropdownField::create("QualificationTypeID", "", $QualificationTypes)->setAttribute('placeholder','Type of degree')->setEmptyString("Any degree")->addExtraClass("chosen-select"),
        DropdownField::create("CourseName", "", Qualification::get()->sort("Name")->map("Name","Name"))->setAttribute('placeholder','Course')->setEmptyString("Any Course")->addExtraClass("chosen-select"),
        DropdownField::create("CityID", "", City::getCitiesWithInstitutions()->sort("Name")->map())->setAttribute('placeholder','City')->setEmptyString("Any city")->addExtraClass("chosen-select")
    ));
    $actions     = new FieldList(array(
        FormAction::create("doSearch")->setTitle("Find a College")
    ));
    $validator   = ZenValidator::create();
    $validator->addRequiredFields(array(
        'QualificationTypeID' => 'Please select a Degree'
    ));
    $form        = new Form($this, 'findthem', $fields, $actions, $validator);
    $form->addExtraClass("form-inline college-search")->setAttribute("data-toggle", "validator");
    $form->loadDataFrom($this->request->postVars());
    $form->disableSecurityToken();
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Have you search for any tutorial or tried something? If you have, I think you better mention what you've done, and on which step you fail.

Comment: Did you see the code that I posted above?  That is what I've done so far  with the help of a friend who had just enough spare time to help me out.  Trying to convert the Courses drop down menu into an Auto-Suggest textfield.

Comment: Do you have any custom javascript, or are you relying purely on Chosen for this functionality? It is probably worth taking a look at [how silverstripe-tagfield](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-tagfield/blob/master/code/TagField.php#L199-L236) does [a similar thing](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-tagfield/blob/master/js/TagField.js#L53-L70).

Comment: Not sure.  My ability to do this code is very limited, especially on this framework.  Best way for me to learn is literally giving me the code or some example based on the code I have and telling me how it works.

Comment: Ok, you could probably use that module and set the options to your custom DataList instead of Tags

Comment: There is a ready-to-use module for this, e.g. https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-autocomplete Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

The Hotels.com example you gave is slightly different to what your are trying to do as you have multiple fields which makes it a bitter harder.

Say for instance you had one field "Search for a college" you could use something like [Jquery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)! and then build a simple [SilverStripe function](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/controllers/introduction/)! that returns objects based on what the user enters.

I would recommend reading the page above regarding SilverStripe controllers as you'll need to know a bit about how they function e.g. Routing and Actions.

Here's a simple example of the Autocomplete integration might look like. A SilverStripe function would need to handle the backend side of this.

```
$('.product-search').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl : pageURL + '/CollegeSearch',
    minChars : 3,
    onSearchStart : function(input) {
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'searchKeyword',
            'eventLabel': input.query
        });
    },
    onSelect : function(suggestion) {
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'searchProduct',
            'eventLabel': suggestion.value
        });
        window.location = suggestion.data;
    }
});
```

And a super simple PHP function

```
public function Index()
{
    if ($query = $this->request->getVar('query')) {
        $colleges = $this->GetColleges($query); // another function that does a search
        $results = array();
        if($colleges->count() > 0){
            foreach($colleges as $college){
                $results[] = array(
                                'value' => $college->Title,
                                'data' => $college->AbsoluteLink()
                            );
            }
        }
        $suggestions = array('suggestions' => $results);
        $converted = convert::array2json($suggestions);
        return $converted;
    }
    return false;
}
```